# ASP.NET Ajax Toolkit Calendar Extender distorted dates

Tags: asp.net, ajax, calendarextender

I am using asp.net ajax calendar extender in my web application. It is showing distorted dates / characters when i open the calendar. I tried to search online to anything similar but can't find it. After opening and closing the calendar control many times, dates disappears and not selectable at all.
I am using same calendar extender in another web application on same machine without any issues.

[image]
[image]

Never faced this issue before. Tried to search online but can't find any solution for this unexpected issue.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay i figured this out by updating the Ajax Control Toolkit version to latest available (20.1.0).